# How to create the text embellishments presented in Sturm's sanitize-umlaut package documentation

Tags: pdftex, minted, text-decorations

Prof. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm included some interesting enhancement of the text in his [documentation](https://ftpmirror1.infania.net/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/sanitize-umlaut/sanitize-umlaut.pdf) for the [sanitize-umlaut package](https://ctan.org/pkg/sanitize-umlaut?lang=en) that I'd like to duplicate in my LaTeX document.

I've tried to re-create the original sanitize-umlaut.tex file by downloading what files there are on [Github](https://github.com/T-F-S/sanitize-umlaut) to no avail. I'm missing something but not conversant enough to know what to do.

I am particularly interested in the text highlighting feature Sturm creates at multiple places in his documentation:

[image: text highlighting in Sturm documentation]

I'd appreciate it if anyone is familiar enough with this type of flourish to point me to a sample snippet of code to create such a text effect.

Comment: @Marcel Krüger - Hi Marcel ... worked like a charm ... can you post your link as an answer so I can give you credit? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the  source code you can see that these blocks are created with a command called `\myverb`. This is defined in [`sanitize-umlaut.dox.sty`](https://github.com/T-F-S/sanitize-umlaut/blob/master/doc/latex/sanitize-umlaut/sanitize-umlaut.doc.sty#L74-L78) as

> ```tex
> \DeclareTotalTCBox{\myverb}{ O{} v }{tile,fontupper=\ttfamily,nobeforeafter,
>   tcbox raise base,boxsep=0.5mm,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,boxrule=0.3mm,
>   colback=yellow!10,
>   borderline horizontal={0.3mm}{0pt}{red!50},
>   #1}{#2}
> ```

This requires the `tcolorbox` package. If you want to better understand the definition you can look at the [`tcolorbox` manual for `\DeclareTotalTCBox`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf?page=18).

**Update:**

I asked, in response to egreg's answer below (Thank you egreg!), if there is a "straightforward way to be able to output the final (expanded) LaTeX **text** instead of the **raw** LaTeX **code**, e.g. instead of printing out '\textbf{Source} $\rightsquigarrow$ \textbf{Migration}', \sverb prints out 'Source ⇝ Migration'?"

I've made a feeble attempt to adjust egreg's answer to output the **final** LaTeX **text** instead of the **raw** LaTeX **code**. Instead of having \s**verb** print out:

'\textbf{Source} $\rightsquigarrow$ \textbf{Migration}'

my adjustments (which did not work) were made to have \s**text** print out:

'Source ⇝ Migration'

My adjustments include changing '\s**verb**' to '\s**text**', '\s**verb**vrule' to '\s**text**vrule', and removing '**\ttfamily**'.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\stext}{O{current}v}{\mbox{%
  \colorlet{current}{.}%
  \color{red!50}%
  \vbox{
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.6pt}%
    \hrule height 0.6pt
    \hbox{\colorbox{yellow!10}{\color{#1}#2}}%
    \edef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
    \hrule height 0.6pt
    \kern-\dimexpr0.6pt+\tpd\relax
  \expandafter}\expandafter\stextvrule\expandafter{\tpd}%
}}
\newcommand{\stextvrule}[1]{\vrule width 0pt depth \dimexpr0.6pt+#1\relax\relax}
```

So now instead of the following output with \s**verb**:

[image: \textbf{Source} $\rightsquigarrow$ \textbf{Migration}]

\s**text** still prints the **raw** LaTeX **code**:

[image: \stext]

When what I'm looking for is simply:

[image: Source ⇝ Migration]

Apologies for not being more specific as part of my original posting, as I did not appreciate that **\myverb** was intended for verbatim code output *only*.

Any thoughts on how to have \s**text** print:

[image: Source ⇝ Migration]

would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed answer!!

Comment: @RosesBouquet I'm not sure you should edit Marcel's answer in this way. If you have some new request you didn't make in your question, ask a follow up one.

Comment: @egreg - I was not sure exactly what to do ... whether to post a new question, or add to my original posting ... I guess I did not want to bore the SE community with too many details about what I was looking for ... Thank you for the comment ... When I have a moment, I will post a new question. Thanks again for all your thoughts !!

Answer (score 2):

Of course Thomas Sturm would use `tcolorbox`. But the same can be achieved with some simpler (albeit lower level) trickery.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sverb}{O{current}v}{\mbox{%
  \colorlet{current}{.}%
  \color{red!50}%
  \vbox{
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.6pt}%
    \hrule height 0.6pt
    \hbox{\colorbox{yellow!10}{\color{#1}\ttfamily#2}}%
    \edef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
    \hrule height 0.6pt
    \kern-\dimexpr0.6pt+\tpd\relax
  \expandafter}\expandafter\sverbvrule\expandafter{\tpd}%
}}
\newcommand{\sverbvrule}[1]{\vrule width 0pt depth \dimexpr0.6pt+#1\relax\relax}

\begin{document}

Some text \sverb|\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}| some text

Some text \sverb[blue!40]|abc| some text

\end{document}
```

The optional argument is for setting a color for the verbatim material as shown in the second example.

The idea is to build a `\vbox`, but we need to precisely set its depth so the baseline of the verbatim material is the same as the surrounding material. Some other trickery allows to cover our tracks by adding a zero width rule as deep as the `\vbox` would be without backing up.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ... I haven't tried your answer as yet, but it seems interesting and a nice option to have going forward ... I'll ned to dedicate a bit of time to work it into my project ... the question is: How do I accept two great answers?

Comment: @RosesBouquet I can survive without a green tick. 

Comment: It's the extra effort that SE'ers like yourself that I cannot thank enough ... for what it is worth ... unless I was seeing things that were not actually there, I did notice that the \myverb solution had the depth a bit off ... so I appreciate the bit of extra tweaking ... I thought Sturm's use in his documentation looked great, and I wanted to add his code (now yours) to my basket of tools that I'm hoping can help convey a message that won't clobber readers over the head, but communicate a message ... as smoothly as possible. Thank you again for the added edit that I will try to test soon.

Comment: The \sverb works well ... Thank you! I couldn't help but notice that the \sverb NewDocumentCommand prints out the verbatim LaTeX code. Now this might sound like I'm backtracking a bit, but is there a straightforward way to be able to output the final LaTeX text instead of the raw LaTeX code, e.g. instead of printing out "\textbf{Source} $\rightsquigarrow$ \textbf{Migration}", \sverb prints out "Source ⇝ Migration"? Apologies for the odd question ... I wouldn't mind defining a second, separate command, e.g. "\sverbtext" instead of "\sverb" ! Thank you for all your help!