# Add lines (NOT a box) above and below text (similar to verbatim) in a non-verbatim format

Tags: verbatim

This is a follow-on question to a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649630/how-to-create-the-text-embellishments-presented-in-sturms-sanitize-umlaut-packa/650294?noredirect=1#comment1621040_650294) on SE where it was suggested I create a new question.

**Question:** How to add lines (NOT a box) above and below *non-verbatim* **text** while maintaining access to ALL the traditional LaTeX **text** attributes including but not limited to fontfamily, fontshape (including italics, bolding, etc.), text color, etc.

This would include the ability to control the attributes of the lines above and below (together or separately) including but not limited to the line **thickness**, **separation** (above and/or below, together or separately) of the lines from the text, the **color(s)** of the lines (together or separately, single or progressive), and the **fill color(s)** (single or progressive) between the lines.

The numerous SE questions and answers I've reviewed do **NOT** meet the criteria I am looking for.

I've been able to meet a few of the above requirements using a combination of **verbatim** and **fancyvrb** in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\centering
\begin{varwidth}{0.33\linewidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, fontfamily=courier, fontshape=it, numbers=none, frame=lines, framerule=0.7mm, framesep=3mm, rulecolor=\color{red}, fillcolor=\color{yellow}]
\textbf{Source} \textrightarrow \textbf{Migration}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{varwidth}
\par}

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

However, if I try to substitute **$\rightsquigarrow$** for **\textrightarrow**, I get the following LaTeX error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> Source $\rightsquigarrow 
                                    $ Migration
l.12 Source $\rightsquigarrow$ Migration
```

So for some reason, my attempt to insert the equivalent of an Inline Equation results in an error.

Also, my attempt to **fill in the space** between the two lines (e.g. fillcolor=\color{yellow}) fails when employing the above **verbatim** and **fancyvrb** code.

As outlined in the previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649630/how-to-create-the-text-embellishments-presented-in-sturms-sanitize-umlaut-packa/650294?noredirect=1#comment1621040_650294) on SE, I am attempting to reproduce the image that appeared in Dr. Thomas F. Sturm's [sanitize-umlaut package](https://ctan.org/pkg/sanitize-umlaut?lang=en) for *verbatim* **text**:

[image: Sturm's verbatim text]

but for straightforward, run-of-the-mill, **non-verbatim**  **text** (e.g. \textbf{}, `$<equation>$`, etc.).

I'm looking for a way to present **text** in the format (displayed above) in Sturm's documentation ***without*** the limitations I've encountered when using **verbatim** based code.

(Special thanks to egreg and Marcel Krüger for their assistance!)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You have two separate issues here. First: the exact error you got is because `\rightsquigarrow` is a symbol that is not available in base latex. You have to load one of the symbol fonts to access it (e.g. `amssymb`). But even if you load the font, compilation will still fail, but this time because the math environment.

Comment: The missing yellow color seems to be internal to the fancyvrb pacakge; if you replace `frame=lines` by `frame=single` the color shows up. If you replace by `frame=leftline` you see a bit of an issue: the color only shows between the left line and the start of verbatim text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\centering
\begin{varwidth}{0.33\linewidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, codes={\catcode`\$=3},fontfamily=courier, fontshape=it, numbers=none, frame=lines, framerule=0.7mm, framesep=3mm, rulecolor=\color{red}, fillcolor=\color{yellow}]
\textbf{Source} $\rightsquigarrow$ \textbf{Migration}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{varwidth}
\par}

\end{document}
```

I made two changes, first is that I loaded `\usepackage{amssymb}` which provided the `\rightsquigarrow` symbol.
Second is that I enabled math mode with the `` codes={\catcode`$=3} `` invocation, as explained in the fancyvrb documentation (section 4.1.17 on Catcode characters):

[image]

---

Actually, reading your question again: **if you don't want to use verbatim, why use `fancyvrb` at all**? If you just want to draw a box with some lines and colors, use something like [`mdframed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed?lang=en) instead. E.g. (I did my best to reproduce the settings you listed for the frames.)

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

{\centering
\begin{varwidth}{0.33\linewidth}
        \begin{mdframed}[skipabove=3mm,skipbelow=3mm,linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=yellow,linewidth=0.7mm,leftline=false,rightline=false]
                \textbf{A} $\rightsquigarrow$ \textsc{b}
        \end{mdframed}
\end{varwidth}
\par}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

---

Looking at your previous question and the linked reference file, it seems that you want to use it to create an in-line highlighting effect? In that case you should use `tcolorbox` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\myhl}{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,toprule=2pt, bottomrule=2pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
  right=1pt,left=1pt,arc=0pt,boxsep=0pt,
  colframe=red,colback=yellow!10!white}

\MakeRobust\myhl


\begin{document}

Some text before \myhl{\textbf{A} $\rightsquigarrow$ \textsc{b}} some text after


\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

**Update from OP**: Latest image of what I was looking for from the beginning:

[image: Latest lined text image.]

Perfect! Thank you Willie Wong!!

Comment: I think you may have hit-the-nail-on-the-head...(if that is an OK expression to use) ... REALLY close to what I had imagined. Let me have a look at your answer to see how I can add the values as options for \myhl[ ... ] ! Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Be warned that the `tcolorbox` documentation is... **very long**. It took me about 5 minutes (and I sort of know what i am looking for) to find the keys to do that little bit of work I did. Have fun reading. :-)

Comment: (The `\MakeRobust` call is in case you need to use the highlighting within a movable context, like `\section{...}`.)

Comment: The option you already provided. e.g. toprule=2pt, bottomrule=2pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, top=1mm,bottom=1mm, right=1pt,left=1pt,arc=0pt,boxsep=0pt,
  colframe=red,colback=yellow!10!white ... are more than I was looking for ... linewidth, linecolor, backgroundcolor, spacingfromtext are the key options I'd like to be able to specify as part of \myhl[ ... ] ... Thank you again ... This may sound silly, but you might have the makings of a new package here ... as best I can tell, there is nothing out there that can do this ... Thanks again

Comment: I was wondering what the \MakeRobust was all about ... Thanks! I REALLY think this could be a new, separate LaTeX package ... I've not see anything else like it anywhere!!

Comment: OK ... I've adjusted some of the options in the \newtcbox macro ... I renamed it to txhlines ... to: \newtcbox{txhlines}{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base, toprule=0.5pt, bottomrule=0.5pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, top=1pt, bottom=1pt, right=1pt, left=1pt, arc=0pt, boxsep=0pt, colframe=red, colback=yellow!10!white}. Now when I run the code on \txhlines{\textbf{Source} $\rightsquigarrow$ \textbf{Migration}}, I get the image I've uploaded above! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for ... Thank you Willie Wong!!

Comment: Now all I need to do is figure out how to make a few of the parameters as options for the new \txhlines macro, e.g. toprule=0.5pt, bottomrule=0.5pt, top=1pt, bottom=1pt, colframe=red, colback=yellow!10!white ! Perfect!

Comment: Final adjustments to the \txhlines macro include:
   toprule=0.7pt, bottomrule=0.7pt, top=2pt, bottom=2pt 
for an updated definition for \txhlines of: 

\newtcbox{txhlines}{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base, toprule=0.7pt, bottomrule=0.7pt,%
leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, top=2pt, bottom=2pt, right=1pt, left=1pt,%
arc=0pt, boxsep=0pt, colframe=red, colback=yellow!10!white}
\MakeRobust\txhlines. 

(I will post samples of how I will be using the \txhlines macro)

Simply Perfect ! Thank you Willie Wong!!